# Php help for create foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i'm new on Php, i need a litle help for create a foreach loop.
My data come from my csv file, in my csv file i have some column with title like product name, productref, i want to create a table with the number of the spare part, the ref of the spare part and the description of the spare part.

All the three elements are display on a table, one columns with the number, one with the ref and one with the name.
My columns have all the same name for number who is N with $i who i want to increment, reference is relied to the column ref with $i and same for the description it's called ref with $i.
Maybe i'm wrong don't hesitate to corrected me.
<?php

```
$i =1;
$c= 0;

$desc = 'Description'.$i;
$re = 'ref'.$i;
$nu = 'N'.$i;

$description = $tabData[(string)$desc];
$ref = $tabData[(string)$re];
$num = $tabData[(string)$nu];
?>

<table style="height: 19px; width: 500px;">
            <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 92px;border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $num[$c];?></td>
        <td style="width: 300px;border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $description[$c];?></td>
        <td style="width: 199px;border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $ref[$c];?></td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

With this code i can display one line but now i have to create a loop to increment the i for take the right information and loop to create new table when he found data.[mycsvfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OntWK.png)
Thank for ur help.
[my var_dump of my tabData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCQVu.png)

[This is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKndg.png)
[var_export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIhYG.png)

```
array ( 'productname' => array ( 0 => 'Chauffe pain', 1 => 'Chauffe pain1', 2 => 'Chauffe pain2', 3 => 'Chauffe pain3', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'productref' => array ( 0 => 'CCP4', 1 => 'CCP41', 2 => 'CCP42', 3 => 'CCP43', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N1' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '1', 2 => '1', 3 => '1', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description1' => array ( 0 => 'couvercle', 1 => 'couvercle1', 2 => 'couvercle1', 3 => 'couvercle1', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref1' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP41', 1 => '0317CCP441', 2 => '0317CCP441', 3 => '0317CCP441', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N2' => array ( 0 => '2', 1 => '2', 2 => '2', 3 => '2', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description2' => array ( 0 => 'Plaque de fixation', 1 => 'couvercle2', 2 => 'couvercle2', 3 => 'couvercle2', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref2' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP42', 1 => '0317CCP441', 2 => '0317CCP441', 3 => '0317CCP441', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N3' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description3' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref3' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N4' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description4' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => 'couvercle4', 2 => 'couvercle4', 3 => 'couvercle4', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref4' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '0317CCP441', 2 => '0317CCP441', 3 => '0317CCP441', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N5' => array ( 0 => '5', 1 => '5', 2 => '5', 3 => '5', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description5' => array ( 0 => 'R�sistance', 1 => 'couvercle2', 2 => 'couvercle2', 3 => 'couvercle2', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref5' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP35', 1 => '0317CCP442', 2 => '0317CCP442', 3 => '0317CCP442', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N6' => array ( 0 => '6', 1 => '6', 2 => '6', 3 => '6', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description6' => array ( 0 => 'Plaque sup�rieure', 1 => 'couvercle3', 2 => 'couvercle3', 3 => 'couvercle3', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref6' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP46', 1 => 'couvercle2', 2 => 'couvercle2', 3 => 'couvercle2', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N7' => array ( 0 => '7', 1 => '7', 2 => '7', 3 => '7', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description7' => array ( 0 => 'Plot', 1 => '0317CCP442', 2 => '0317CCP442', 3 => '0317CCP442', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref7' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP37', 1 => 'couvercle3', 2 => 'couvercle3', 3 => 'couvercle3', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N8' => array ( 0 => '8', 1 => '8', 2 => '8', 3 => '8', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description8' => array ( 0 => 'Interrupteur', 1 => '0317CCP442', 2 => '0317CCP442', 3 => '0317CCP442', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref8' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP48', 1 => 'couvercle4', 2 => 'couvercle4', 3 => 'couvercle4', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N9' => array ( 0 => '9', 1 => '9', 2 => '9', 3 => '9', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description9' => array ( 0 => 'Voyant', 1 => '0317CCP442', 2 => '0317CCP442', 3 => '0317CCP442', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref9' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP39', 1 => 'couvercle5', 2 => 'couvercle5', 3 => 'couvercle5', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N10' => array ( 0 => '10', 1 => '10', 2 => '10', 3 => '10', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => ';', ), 'Description10' => array ( 0 => 'Cordon d\'alimentation', 1 => '0317CCP442', 2 => '0317CCP442', 3 => '0317CCP442', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref10' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP310', 1 => 'couvercle3', 2 => 'couvercle3', 3 => 'couvercle3', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'N11' => array ( 0 => '11', 1 => '11', 2 => '11', 3 => '11', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'Description11' => array ( 0 => 'Base', 1 => '0317CCP443', 2 => '0317CCP443', 3 => '0317CCP443', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), 'ref11' => array ( 0 => '0317CCP411', 1 => 'couvercle4', 2 => 'couvercle4', 3 => 'couvercle4', 4 => '', 5 => '', 6 => '', 7 => '', 8 => '', 9 => '', 10 => '', ), )
```

Comment: Can you edit the post please, and include the items that you've posted as images?

Comment: And please make it a `var_export`, instead of a dump - that gives us actual PHP code that we can copy&paste to recreate your sample data without any additional formatting steps.

Comment: And where does this data come from? If you are in control of that, then it would probably make more sense to have it grouped by the product to begin with (i.e., have an array of arrays, where the keys on the _second_ level are `productname`, `productref`, etc.), instead of the other way around. That you could then loop over with a `foreach` loop, without bothering about the top level index yourself.

Comment: Yep i will edit the post for the images and make the var_export, thank u guys

Comment: Sorry can't include the images as the item of my post ....

Comment: If u want, i can send u in private

Comment: Can you show us your _attempt_ at creating a loop for this at least?

Comment: @Noobs Check out https://www.php.net/fgetcsv for fetching data from file, and then `foreach($csv_rows as $row) { echo "what's needed for each row"; }`

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Yep i already check this, it's good i can fetch the data but i can't loop for create my table correctly, it's work with the data in rows but i want to fetch the data by column, it's means on one rows i have all the data for one product and the rows after is a another product and CBroe i don' t really understand the foreach, all my attempt is really bad it's why i ask for help

Comment: @Noobs Hmm.. foreach is a really basic construct. Could it be that you're trying to do things in the wrong order? Perhaps leave this issue for an hour or two and read up on the things mentioned here? And then come back here?